# accessing ajax toolkit outside salesforce

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, salesforce

I have a simple html page in my system. I am trying to access my org details using the ajax toolkit. But I am unable to do so. Any idea how can I access salesforce data in a simple html page in my system using javascript/ jquery??

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="connection.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="apex.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
sforce.connection.init('sessionId', 'https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/26.0');
j$(document).ready(function(){
    var result = sforce.connection.query("Select Name, Id from User");
    var records = result.getArray("records");
    for (var i=0; i< records.length; i++) {
        var record = records[i];
        console.log(record.Name + " -- " + record.Id);
    }
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is not a specific question, I will try and answer in general what needs to be done.

1. You will need to enable "Remote Access" to the Salesforce Rest API in your org.
2. Obtain an OAuth 2.0 access token to access the Rest API and then use the Rest API to access it.

There are a good number of resources in the developer.force.com network. Some useful links I used in the past,

1. http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_at_Salesforce.com
2. http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_REST_API
3. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index.htm

The second link contains a full example in Java. This can be converted to JS. And the third link provides complete reference to the rest API.